# Android EditText no input with external blueTooth Hardware Keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard, android-edittext

on testing my app on my tablet (Android 4.1.1 Asus) i find out that my bluetooth keyboard is not supported on my edittext. There is no input! Using the softkeyboard is no problem.

This is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <EditText android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:id="@+id/txtTuneScript" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />              
</LinearLayout>
```

I'm missing any attibute for the editText? Any idea?
Using an other app on the tablet like droidEdit, the bluetooth keyboard works fine...

Answer (score 2):

I got this problem with a KeyEventListner which returned true.

```
    ed.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View view, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
            if (keyEvent.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER
                || keyEvent.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_TAB) {
                useData(result);
                finish();
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

The surprising part is that virtual keyboard have working input while it still handle events.

Comment: I was implementing a custom EditText and overriding the `onKeyPreIme(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)` method; I was making it return `false`, and the input from a physical keyboard wasn't working. Thanks to your answer I was able to change this method and make it return `true`, and now the physical keyboard is working again!